# Sending transaction directly to miner on private network?

Tags: go-ethereum, private, p2p

I am trying to understand how one node can send a transaction to another node (miner or full) directly rather than waiting P2P network to distribute it?

Say I have two non-miner nodes A and B and one miner to C on a private network.

```
  B
 / \
A   C
```

Is it possible to send a transaction to the miner directly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Generally speaking such private services will offer an API or RPC endpoint that allows you to get transactions included in blocks, without broadcasting them to the public network.

Here's an [example from taich.network](https://taichi.network/#sendPrivateTransaction):

```
curl -X POST   https://api.taichi.network:10001/rpc/public   -H 'content-type: application/json'   -d '{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"eth_sendPrivateTransaction",
    "params":[
       "0xf86c0785080ad9f00082627094302fc4c7231589239912d62ec7ea6266d771cfdf88024a8d93446ac0008025a01450674b2c65e7902d9f03cbf899bb1063b2b14ca5e6a7fa5616d420b67196c1a049063bc399b171b0c570aeba9d33bc78a550701c3e95238947b90f1ccf841032"
    ],
    "id":1
}'
```